# Parsing OIDs in CertificatePolicies from CSR object in CX509CertificateRequestPkcs10 in c#

Tags: c#, x509, csr, pkcs

I am trying to parse a CSR, CX509CertificateRequestPkcs10 object to read the OIDs in the Certificate policies in extension but I am not able get to it.

```
CX509CertificateRequestPkcs10 request = new CX509CertificateRequestPkcs10();
request.InitializeDecode(csr, EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64_ANY);
request.X509Extensions;
var certPolicies = (CCertificatePolicies)(extensions[iter]);
AsnEncodedData asndata = new AsnEncodedData(certificatePolicyExtn.Oid, 
certificatePolicyExtn.RawData);
List<string> data = new List<string>(asndata.Format(true).Split('\n'));
var CertPoliciesList = data.Where(x => x.Contains(AkOidFriendlyName)).ToList();
```

Comment: Isn't it something like `foreach (ICertificatePolicy pol in certPolicies) { ... }`? (It looks like ICertificatePolicies is IEnumerable and returns ICertificatePolicy values)

Comment: I tried that as well. My issue is not iteratin it but instead getting the object of x509Extension Type and not some com  object

Comment: There's no built-in X509Extension for certificate policies (or, until next version, to read  PKCS#10).  Bouncy Castle may have one, the COM type you're already using has one, or you could write one using something like the `System.Formats.Asn1` package.  Parsing the string from AsnEncodedData.Format is definitely not recommended.